# How to POST binary data using Rest Client?

Tags: ruby, http, post, binary-data, rest-client

I am trying to read in an audio file of type wav or amr from a HTML form using Rest Client. I have the code to do this in PHP.

```
$filename = $_FILES['f1']['name'];

public function getFile($filename) {
      if (file_exists($filename)) {
          $file_binary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
          return $file_binary;
       } else {
          throw new Exception("File not found.");
       }
  }
```

I need to convert this code to Ruby and I am having trouble doing so as I am a relative novice when it comes to Ruby.

Comment: data = params[:f1]
file = File.open(data, "rb") {|io| io.read}

url = "...."

response = RestClient.post url, file, :Authorization => "Bearer #{@access_token}", :Accept => 'application/json', :Content_Type => 'audio/wav'

rescue => e
  @error = e.message
ensure
  return erb :speech
end

Answer (score 3):

According to [RestClient's repo](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb):

```
def self.post(url, payload, headers={}, &block)
    Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => url, :payload => payload, :headers => headers, &block)
  end
```

This snippet of code simply sends a file:

```
file = File.open('path/to/file.extension', 'r')
RestClient.post("your_url_to_the_endpoint", file)
```

So I assume all you still need to do is to set the headers:

```
begin 
file = File.open(params[:f1], "rb") 
url = "...." 
response = RestClient.post url, file, {:Authorization => "Bearer #{@access_token}", :Accept => 'application/json', :Content_Type => 'audio/wav'} 

rescue => e 
@error = e.message 
ensure 
return erb :speech 
end
```